# Is there any blocking web service API in Play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS), the Play 2.3 WS API is async. However, I need a blocking WS client to access external web service.

Is there any blocking WS API in Play 2.3? Or do I have to refer to primitive scala API?

Comment: I don't think so. Play only provide async call. Only option for you to block the call wait until get response with timeout

Comment: Why do you need it to be blocking? Can't you just put callbacks on the async call?

Comment: maybe that helps you http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: You can always Await.result

Answer (score 0):

You could force it probably using something like `Await.result(Future.successful("FOO"))` but please check first if you really need to block. In most (almost all) cases you don't have to. Because if you block within asynchronous code you're throwing all advantages brought to you by that overboard.

It might be a good idea to refactor your code base to handle things asynchronous which is a bit challenging if done for the first time but it definitely pays off.